# Why are my Astrid and Tasks reminders late sometimes?

Tags: to-do-list

```
Samsung GT-I8160 Galaxy Ace II
Stock Android 4.1.2
```

I used Astrid for a couple of years, and now I use [Tasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tasks). But both of them has the similar issue: sometimes reminders are late. What may be the reason? How it can be fixed?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about "late"? Do they show up a certain amount of time after the set time (e.g. always one hour late)? Do they only show up next time you start the app? Or is there some other pattern of lateness?

Comment: @DanHulme, I can't catch some pattern: here are various tasks (repeated or not) with various lateness (minutes or hours). They show up without any activity for my part, just late.

Answer (score 1):

Reminders for tasks with due dates and due times should wake up the device and fire at the exact time. If this is not what you are experiencing you can add an item to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/abaker/tasks/issues) with more details and I can look in to it.

If a task has only a due date without a due time then other factors come into play, but in most circumstances the reminder should fire at the default reminder time found in the reminder settings preferences.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/abaker/tasks/issues/234)